# как установить фокус на следуюшую ячейку когда нажав клавишу Enter в java swing

Tags: java

как установить фокус на следуюшую ячейку JTable когда нажав  клавишу Enter в java swing

Comment: Какой компонент? JTable?

Comment: да JTable. извиняаюс